# Does it matter which public XMPP server one chooses?

Tags: xmpp

When signing up for an [XMPP](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) account on a public server, does it matter which public server one selects?  If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

It *kind* of does. If the public server you're on dosen't have the option to talk to other servers turned on (and this is not uncommon), well, you can only talk to people on the same server. If they do, and your server can find the other server *and* various conditions for inter server communication are met, things just work.

In short? Safe option is to use the same server as the people you want to talk to. Else, in many cases it dosen't matter, but make sure you check that the people you want to talk to can see you

Comment: Thanks. That's interesting.  Is there any way to know if the server has the option to talk to other servers enabled?  It it a simple Boolean setting (all or nothing), or is there a whitelist/blacklist that the operator has to include?

Comment: I haven't run a server in *ages*. I think the setting called "federation" is all or nothing, when I last ran it tho.